# Module cyclic import

Tags: python, importerror, python-import

In my project I use the module `interaction` which contains some "interfaces" for accessing to the system functions. For example I have 2 modules implement the different interfaces and the one of them is depends on other interface.

**module1.py**:

```
value = 5

def init():
    pass

def provide_int():
    global value
    return value
```

**module2.py**:

```
def init():
    import interaction
    global value
    value = str(interaction.int_provider.provide_int())

def provide_string():
    global value
    return value
```

So I want to use it the same way:

**interaction.py**:

```
from importlib import import_module

globals()['int_provider'] = import_module('module1')
globals()['int_provider'].init()
globals()['str_provider'] = import_module('module2')
globals()['str_provider'].init()
```

So during initialization the `module2` (calling init function) I get an ImportError because of cyclic import. 
This example is synthetic of course, but the common state is the same.

I have 2 question:
1. Is it right way to use the "global" module like my `interaction.py` proxying the interfaces?
2. How can I defeat this cyclic import?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest doing away with the `init` functions and making the `provide_string()` function set up its values when they are first called. Because very little happens at module load time, there won't be problems with modules referring to each other. Furthermore, you can simplify your `interaction` module by using the `as` keyword with regular imports:

iteraction.py:

```
 import module1 as int_provider
 import module2 as string_provider
```

module1.py:

```
 value = 5

 def provide_int():
     return value # no global statement necessary, since we don't assign to value
```

module2.py:

```
 value = None # this will be set up after the first call to provide_string

 def provide_string():
     global value # global is needed, since we may assign a new string to value
     if value is None:
         import interaction
         value = str(interaction.int_provider.provide_int())
     return value
```

Answer (score 0):

**How can I defeat this cyclic import?**

You could use lazily-created providers using something like [django.utils.functional.SimpleLazyObject](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/functional.py#L278). This way, you will initialize the provider the moment any attribute of it is accessed. You'll have to remember to **memoize** the result in `SimpleLazyObject` as the function passed will be **reevaluated** every time.

Usage:

```
def init_str_provider():
    if not hasattr(init_str_provider, 'provider'):
        init_str_provider.provider = import_module('module2')
        init_str_provider.provider.init()
    return init_str_provider.provider

str_provider = SimpleLazyObject(init_str_provider)
```

**Is it right way to use the "global" module like my `interaction.py` proxying the interfaces?**

If I was to create such structure with interfaces, I'd rather go with:

- A provider-class-registration method in `interfaces.py`.
- Using classes to represent a provider (easier interfacing due to inheritance!).
- Provide a `get_provider(name)` function in `interfaces.py` to allow lazy provider-initialization.

Such decoupling makes it **way easier** to test and mock separate providers, and leaves more space for customization. Also, if you'd ever need to **extend** behaviour of one provider inside another, class objects store their state **inside** them, not in module-level. This way you can actually inherit from other providers without worrying that any child provider will tinker with a stand-alone base provider's internals.